# Ng Zorro table - Items in table have type `any`(bad Intellisense)

Tags: html, angular, datatable, ng-zorro-antd

Consider having this simple table:

```html
<nz-table #table [nzData]="users">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of table.data">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{item.lastName}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</nz-table>
```

And this .ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

interface User {
    firstName: string;
    latName: string;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-list',
    templateUrl: './list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./list.component.scss']
})
export class ListComponent {
    users: User[] = [];
}
```

How can I get intellisense in the html template for the `firstName` and `lastName` fields? My IDE says that the `item` variable has type `any` and it should've been of type `User`.

Why is there a need for the template reference anyways? Why can't we just use `<tr *ngFor="let item of users">` (apart for the fact the pagination is not working)?

Comment: which IDE you are using?

Comment: I am using Intellij

Answer (score 1):

set `nzTemplateMode` as `false` and then there is no need to bind users to `nzData` like this `[nzData]="users"`. Then you can directly use `<tr *ngFor="let item of users">`

```
<nz-table [nzTemplateMode]="false" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of users">
            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
            <td>{{item.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.lastName}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</nz-table>
```

Comment: The same problem appears: the table renders all the data in one page. The pagination is there but it doesn't work (and it cannot work since all the data is in one page)

Comment: Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-start-xqfzbp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)